# Calculate geo location based on distance from other locations

Tags: geography, geodesy

Given a list of entities (or `GeoPosition`s) and their distances from a particular location, how do I find that location's `GeoPosition`?

```
dist = Map[{#, GeoDistance[$GeoLocation, #]}&, GeoNearest["University", $GeoLocation, 5]]
```

[image]

How do I find this point?

```
GeoGraphics[{Thick, GeoMarker[], GeoCircle @@@ dist}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

If you want to try with this data:

```
{{Entity["University", "VanderCookCollegeOfMusic149639"],   Quantity[1.407900938586476, "Miles"]},
 {Entity["University", "IllinoisInstituteOfTechnology145725"], Quantity[1.5607147441441935, "Miles"]},
 {Entity["University", "UniversityOfIllinoisAtChicago145600"],   Quantity[1.6865509085430637, "Miles"]},
 {Entity["University", "ShimerCollege148849"], Quantity[1.7240912464169733, "Miles"]},
 {Entity["University", "IllinoisCollegeOfOptometry145628"],   Quantity[1.7283592978609772, "Miles"]}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm definitely not proud of this, but here's a brute force method that is pretty accurate.

First let's define some functions, cheating and using the built in `GeoDistance` function. We'll also try to minimize the error between the distances we're using as inputs and the distances we're calculating based on our guess `{latitude, longitude}`:

```
geodist[pos1 : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, pos2 : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := GeoDistance[pos1, pos2]

findpt[latlons : {{_, _} ..}, distances_?ListQ] := Module[{solpos}, 
  solpos = {$lat, $lon} /. 
  NMinimize[
   Total[
    Abs@QuantityMagnitude[
     (geodist[{$lat, $lon}, #] & /@ latlons) - distances]], 
   {{$lat, Max[Min[latlons[[All, 1]]] - 10, -90], Min[Max[latlons[[All, 1]]] + 10, 90]},
{$lon, Max[Min[latlons[[All, 2]]] - 10, -180], Min[Max[latlons[[All, 2]]] + 10, 180]}}, 
 Method -> "NelderMead"][[2]];
GeoPosition[solpos]
]
```

The only thing to check is to make sure the distances calculated by `GeoDistance` are in the same units as the input distances.

So let's test:

```
inputlatlon = {39.72, -104.81};
dist = Map[{#, GeoDistance[GeoPosition[inputlatlon], #]} &, 
  GeoNearest["University", GeoPosition[inputlatlon], 5]]
GeoGraphics[{Thick, GeoMarker[GeoPosition[inputlatlon]], 
GeoCircle @@@ dist}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
findpt[QuantityMagnitude[LatitudeLongitude /@ dist[[All, 1]]], dist[[All, 2]]]
```

> `GeoPosition[{39.72, -104.81}]`

```
GeoDistance[%, GeoPosition[inputlatlon]]
```

> `Quantity[2.62342*10^-6, "Feet"]`

Hmmm, not too bad.

```
UnitConvert[%, "Angstroms"]
```

> `Quantity[7996.18, "Angstroms"]`

Damn, 8000 Angstroms...

Comment: Thanks! :) I was holding out to see if someone might come up with a symbolic solution, but it seems like this is the way to go. Angstroms... Mathematica's geodesy is almost as precise as the NSA's spy satellites.